# Merge related files in a makefile using pattern rules

Tags: makefile, bioinformatics

I'm using make to write a biological data analysis pipeline. I have a problem where I am unable to merge related files. For example, say I have four files (although the total number of files, and related files may be more): A_1.fastq A_2.fastq B_1.fastq B_2.fastq. When the pipeline is run in parallel I want each of the files to go through the recipes except the last, where I want related files to be merged e.g. A.merged.bam B.merged.bam. I am unsure how to write a rule like this in make?

**Example makefile**

```
# chip-seq.mk

originalFiles = A_1.fastq A_2.fastq B_1.fastq B_2.fastq
mergedFiles = A.merged.bam B.merged.bam

all: $(mergedFiles)           

%.merged.bam: %_*.sorted.bam
    # merge bam files
    samtools merge $@ $^

%.sorted.bam: %.bam
    # sort bam
    samtools sort $^ $*.sorted

%.bam: %.sam
    # convert sam to bam
    samtools view -bS $^ > $@

%.sam: %.fastq
    # align reads
    bowtie2 -x genome -U $^ -S $@
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with a pure pattern.  How can make match a wildcard like `%_*.sorted.bam` to files on the disk?

You can do it with an explicit list of prerequisites, though, still using a pattern for the rule:

```
# convert originalFiles into a sorted.bam filename
# run $(call cvtFiles,A) to get A files, etc.
cvtFiles = $(patsubst %.fastq,%.sorted.bam,$(filter $1_%,$(originalFiles)))

%.merged.bam:
       samtools merge $@ $^

A.merged.bam: $(call cvtFiles,A)
B.merged.bam: $(call cvtFiles,B)
```

Of course you have to write a new rule for each merged file.

You could use a loop with eval to do it, instead:

```
$(foreach P,$(patsubst %.merged.bam,%,$(mergedFiles)),$(eval $P.merged.bam: $(call cvtFiles,$P)))
```

(not tested...)